# How to show user's location with a UIButton, similar to a slider?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this slider that zooms in and out user's location, keeping it centered on the mapKit - working fine. If I swipe through the map (simulator) to some random point and I want to get user's location again, I just have to click on the slider. The question is: can I do the same with a UIButton? A Button that only gets the current location. I've tried similar code, but it does not work...I guess it must be a simple thing to do but I'm kind of new at IOS...The slider code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *userLoc;

- (IBAction)userLoc:(UISlider *)sender {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(_mapView.userLocation.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(sender.value, sender.value));

    [_mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is: can I do the same with a UIButton?

Yes, you can. A slider has a user-settable value where a button does not, so you'll need to change the values in the `MKCoordinateSpanMake()` call to some appropriate fixed value. And you'll need to change the type associated with the `sender` parameter from `UISlider*` to `UIButton*`. Other than those changes, what you've got should work.